# kopf elasticsearch plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I use kopf plugin for elasticsearch. There is load bar within node on cluster page. This load bar is showing whole server loading or elasticsearch loading?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fwVz.png)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The load is from the whole server.

You can check it from [here](https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf/blob/fd080b34132f77b60c7c4d8dde6f720ecc4a8191/_site/partials/cluster_overview/node_cell.html#L65) and [here](https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf/blob/fd080b34132f77b60c7c4d8dde6f720ecc4a8191/src/kopf/elastic/node.js#L41) from the source code.

`node-progress-bar" title="1min avg: {{node.load_average | number:2}}"`

`this.load_average = getProperty(this.stats, 'os.load_average');`

According to [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/cluster-nodes-stats.html#os-stats), the `os.load_average` is from the operating system:

> The os flag can be set to retrieve statistics that concern the operating system: